# Excel Collection Variable

Tags: excel, vba, collections, module, scope

Let's say we have two workbooks identical with respect to the VBA functionality; however, the data-sets will be different. The VBA code stores some data on a collection variable to facilitate calculations. This variable is called via different modules inside the same workbook. As this variable also exists on the other workbook and these two workbooks should not share the same collection values, how can we make sure the call for collection will only pull the variable from its own workbook?

Will the declaration "Option Private Module" be adequate when declaring the collection variable? Such as:

```
Option Private Module
Public DataCol As New Collection
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52725095/edit) to include more information.  Do you have code you have tried?  In general, you won't be accessing data from another workbook unless you specifically reference [`Workbooks("name").Something`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks).

Comment: Declaring a collection as public inside a normal module isn't often needed. Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Declaring the module as `Option Private Module` will restrict the scope of "Public" variables declared in that module to that specific project. This is similar to `Friend` scope in classes, and analogous to `internal static` in .NET.

Comment: Unless the OP's explicitly created a reference to the second workbook, there is no benefit from [`Option Private Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-private-statement). Even with a reference, if both projects have variables with the same name, you'd have to include the external project name with the variable in order to refer to it.

Comment: @ashleedawg I didn't say there was a *benefit* to using it this way, I was just explaining how it effects scope.

Comment: I realize that, but since it's posted as your answer, it's might imply to the OP that this is something they *should do* or will benefit from. I have a feeling the OP has not created any inter-workbook references, which makes make `Option Private` useless (albeit harmless).

Comment: @ashleedawg Fair enough, although you've already put *way* more effort into this question that I was going to.

Answer (score 2):

### Unlikely to be an issue...

Let's say you have two identical workbooks:

- `Book1.xlsm`, and,
- `Book2.xlsm`

...and both have a Public Variable setup identically, named `X`.

Unless you have ***explicitly* set a Reference** from `Book1` to `Book2`, then `Book1` cannot "see" `X` or other variables/constants/etc that exist within `Book2`.

[image: img]

For example, one way of setting a the reference would be if in `Book1` you went **Tools** > **References** > **Browse** and selected workbook `Book2.xlsm`.

[image: img]

*Even if you did* set a reference between the workbooks, and both have a variable named `X`, `Book1` will always look for an `X` in within itself before looking elsewhere.  You would have to qualify the variable like:

```
Applications.Workbooks("Books2.xlsm").X
```

This applies to all references;  If you have something in your workbook named the same as a "connected" reference, code running in your workbook "looks" first within the procedure, then within the module, then within the workbook, before looking externally to connected references.

Its very unlikely that VBA will refer to a variable in the wrong workbook.

If you often have two identical workbooks open, it's much more likely that **you** will accidentally write or execute code in the wrong workbook,  (I've done it, it's annoying - especially when you close & delete the "garbage workbook", that you actually accidentally just wrote a bunch of code in!)

There should not be very many situations where you have two identical workbooks open; if this is regular practice there is **probably a better way to organize your data storage process**.

---

### Ranges

Note that the same does **not** apply when referring to **worksheet ranges**, etc., with unqualified references.

For example, `Range("A1")` refers to whatever worksheet is "on top" (ie., the last workbook that was clicked, selected, or otherwise activated.

This is why it's important to qualify range references.  One example of a fully qualified range reference is:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

---

## Scope

This discussion falls into the category of **Scope**.

[image: scope]

Read more about what scope is and how to use it to your benefit (and prevent problems) in these links:

- Chip Pearson : [**Understanding Scope of Variables and Procedures in VBA**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx)
- MS Office Support : [**Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications**](https://support.microsoft.com/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications)
- analysistabs.com : [**Scope of Variables in Excel VBA**](https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/scope-of-variables/)

---

### *Truly* Global Variables

Incidentally, there's also a way to create **truly** Global Variables, that can be referenced by other (**non-Office**) applications, and even **after your application has closed** and/or re-opened.

It takes some fairly advanced coding since it involves Windows API's, but Chip Pearson has the steps and sample code available [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/trulyglobalvariables.htm).

Comment: upvote for that retro looking scope diagram. that thing belongs in boogie nights :) (and this is one incredible answer, too)